# A continuous a.e orientation-preserving isometry is locally injective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, riemannian-geometry, inverse-function, isometry

Let $M,N$ be $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds. Let $f:M \to N$, and suppose $f$ is continuous, differentiable almost everywhere (a.e
) **and** that $df$ is an **orientation-preserving** isometry a.e.

**Question:** Is it true that there exist a ball $B_{\epsilon}(p) \subseteq M$ such that $f|_{B_{\epsilon}(p)}$ is injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $M$ be the interval $(0,1)$. Let $\mu$ be a finite, purely singular measure (i.e., singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure) on $M$ that has no atoms and satisfies $\mu(I)>0$ for every nontrivial subinterval $I\subset (0,1)$ ([an example of such $\mu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/612806)). Define 
$$f(x) = x - \mu((0,x))$$
This is a continuous function because $\mu$ is nonatomic. It has  $f'=1$ almost everywhere, because a singular measure has zero derivative a.e. ([stated here, with a reference to Folland's Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53966)).

For every interval $I\subset (0,1)$, by virtue of $\mu(I)>0$ and $\mu$ being singular, there exist subintervals $J_1,J_2\subset I$ such that $\mu(J_1)>|J_1|$ and $\mu(J_2) <|J_2|$ where $|\cdot |$ stands for the length of intervals. This can be proved in general, but is easier to see for the specific example of $\mu$ linked above: $I$ contains a dyadic subinterval $D$, and after $n$ dyadic subdivisions of $D$ its leftmost child $D_n^{-}$ and rightmost child $D_n^+$ satisfy $\mu(D_n^+) = p^n\mu(D)$ and $\mu(D_n^-) = (1-p)^n \mu(D)$. Since both have length $|D|/2^n$, this yields the desired subintervals when $n$ is large enough.

Conclusion: $f$ is not monotone on $I$, and therefore is not injective on any subinterval on $M$.

This example can be promoted to higher dimensions by letting $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d) = (f(x_1), x_2,\dots, x_d)$.

---

To get a positive result, you may want to assume that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous; then $f$ is a Sobolev map, and the theory of quasiregular maps implies that $f$ is discrete and open, hence a local homeomorphism outside of a branch set of topological dimension $\le d-2$. References:

- [Space Mappings with Bounded Distortion](http://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-73) by Reshetnyak - contains the proof that Sobolev maps with appropriate constraints on the derivative $Df$ are discrete and open.
- [Quasiregular Mappings](https://books.google.com/books?id=EV3mCAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_book_similarbooks) by Rickman - covers the same topic from a more topological point of view.
- *Discrete open mappings on manifolds* by J. Väisälä, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Ser. A I Math. 1966, no. 392 - a proof that a discrete open mapping has a branch set of topological dimension at most $d-2$ (proved earlier by Chernavskii in the Euclidean setting).
- [A new characterization of the mappings of bounded length distortion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01026) by  Hajłasz and  Malekzadeh - since your assumption on $Df$ is more restrictive than is required for quasiregular maps, it may be easier to use this source and the Martio-Väisälä article it refers to. If $f$ in your problem is Lipschitz, then it immediately qualifies as a bounded length distortion (BLD) map under the analytic definition, which is known to be equivalent to the geometric definition (see the beginning of this article).

Comment: Thanks! What you are saying is very interesting. Would you mind to elaborate on some points? (1) What do you mean by purely singular? (singular w.r.t the Lebesgue measure?) (2) Can you explain how do you deduce the existence of such intervals $J_1,J_2$ from your assumptions on $\mu$? (3) How do you see that $f'(x)=1$? (4) Do you have a reference for the result you mentioned on the topological dimension $\le d-2$? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I expanded the answer to address these points.

Answer (score 0):

I want to reply to your comment in

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264873/do-curvature-differences-obstruct-a-e-orientation-preserving-isometries/267163#267163

**Question** : Assume that $$f :B\rightarrow
\mathbb{E}^2$$ is a map s.t.

(1) $B$ is a geodesic ball in $S^2(1)$ of radius $\varepsilon$

(2) $df$ is isometric a.e.

(3) a.e. orientation preserving

Then $f$ is not continuous

**EXE** : Gromov's map $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{E}^2$ is not
orientation preserving, since it can view as a limit of piecewise
distance preserving maps that are not an a.e.-orientation-preserving
maps.

**Proof of Question** : Assume that $f$ is continuous. Hence by considering following EXE, we conclude that it is volume preserving

Consider a triangulation $T_i$ of $B_\epsilon (p)$ where each $T_i$ is 2-dimensional geodesic triangle. Since $f$ is orientation preserving then $
f(T_i)$ are not overlapping except measure $0$-set.

Hence we have that $\gamma_i$ is a curve going to $\partial
B_\epsilon(p)$ and $f\circ \gamma_i$ goes to $\partial f(B_\epsilon
(p))$ s.t. $$\lim_i\ {\rm length}\ \gamma_i={\rm
length}\ \partial B_\epsilon (p) \geq \lim_i\ {\rm length}\ f\circ
\gamma_i $$ since $f$ is short.

Hence by isoperimetric inequality, it is a contradiction.

**EXE** : Consider a continuous map $ f: [0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{E}^2$ s.t.
assume that $c(t)=f(t,1)$ is a continuous curve whose image has
2-dimensional.

Hence note that curve $f(t,1-\varepsilon_n)$ where
$\varepsilon_n\rightarrow 0$ has an arbitrary large length $l_n$
with $\lim_n\ l_n=\infty$ Hence $f$ is not isometric on
$[0,1]\times [1-\varepsilon_n,1)$

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your efforts and patience. Can you elaborate on why $f$ should be short? (In one dimensional case we have continuous maps which are orientation-preserving and isometric a.e, and are not short. In fact, such maps need not be Lipschitz. You can take for instance $f(x)=c(x)+x$ where $c(x)$ is the cantor function. (I also gave this example in the question you answered in MO). Thus, I do not see why even when assuming continuity, you can deduce the map is short.

Comment: I modified some in my posting.

Comment: Continuous will not imply "volume preserving".

Comment: I mean that $f$ is continuous, orientation preserving and $df$ is isometric a.e.

Comment: @HKLee: Why would this imply volume-preserving? (It does not.) You need absolute continuity (in dimension 1) and something like absolute continuity on a.e. line (in higher dimensions).